# CORS issues with .Net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting a CORS violation error. I tried every solution I found on this forum and many others, however I just cant get this right. Please help. What am I missing?

Here is my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Mellow.Data;
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MellowDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    builder.Services.AddCors(options=>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCORSPolicy",p =>
        {
            p.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod();   
        });
    });
    
    
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
     
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    //app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
    app.UseCors("MyCORSPolicy");
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

I created an API using .Net Core 6 and consuming it using a React app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by invoking the API using a different endpoint/URL.
In the launchSettings.json I have the following URLs:
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5103;https://localhost:7088"

Initially I used http://localhost:5103 but magically the issue was resolved when I made the call using the latter URL I.E https://localhost:7088.
Problem solved!
[image: launchSettings.json]

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with CORS then. You get CORS violations for all kinds of infrastructure errors, because if the CORS call does not work *for any reason* it's a CORS violation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "MyCORSPolicy";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
..
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyCORSPolicy,
                     p =>
    {
        p.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod();   
    });
});
...
app.UseCors(MyCORSPolicy);
```

You can read [CORS with named policy and middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware)  to know more.